# spark-ec2 sporadic errors - Initial job has not accepted any resources

Tags: apache-spark

Sporadically, I get the following error when running Apache Spark on EC2:

```
WARN scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
```

It happens randomly and the only way to fix is it to shut down the cluster and re start everything. Clearly, this is inefficient. Why does this error randomly occur? I can see in the console all my instances are perfectly fine. I am trying to work with a 6MB file. It can't possibly be out of memory. Every time I attempt to do something on Apache Spark EC2 there seems to be some random error popping up. This recent error occurred when I'm running a program I have run 5'000+ times before. On the same cluster type. Why is there so many sporadic errors? And what does this one even mean considering my instances and master are working perfectly.